# Finding nearest HTML fragment identifier to scroll position with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fragment-identifier

How does one locate the nearest HTML fragment identifier (hashtag href) based on window's current scroll position?

I want to make a bookmarking feature via JS/jQuery that captures the nearest section the user was in when hitting the bookmark button. I don't have access to the backend, so I can't add any hooks/hidden fields, but that shouldn't matter because the fragment IDs *are* my hooks.

I'm thinking jQuery's `.scroll()` handler could be of use, but I'm not sure how to locate the "DOM content at a given scroll position" to know if a new identifier has appeared. Or if that's even the best approach...

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that:

```
$('a [href]').filter(function() {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(this).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
})
.first();
```

Comment: based on : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling

Comment: Thanks Artur. While I found a better approach for my situation (I added it as another answer), this is technically a correct answer to my original question.

Answer (score 1):

While not technically an answer to my original question, this is the more flexible solution I decided to use:

When the user hits "bookmark" jQuery will store the page url with a phantom query string tacked on of `pos=X` where X is the current value of `$('body').scrollTop()`.

When a user wants to revisit his bookmark, the stored URL will be loaded and the inserted jQuery will retrieve the `pos` value and scroll the page to the bookmarked position.

This is ideal because it literally puts the user right back where he/she left off, down to the pixel.

Answer (score 0):

i quite don't understand your question, but to do something on scroll using jquery you can try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100){
            /*you check if identifier has appeared here*/
        }
    });
});
```